# Consulta mysql con múltiples filtros

Tags: php, mysql, sql

como lo dice el titulo pretendo crear una consulta mysql donde me filtre los datos con 4 filtros diferentes en una misma consulta, tengo lo siguiente:

En la base de datos almacena el valor de la variable de los 4 filtros los cuales llamo asi:

````
$filter1 = $rowflt['año'];
$filter2 = $rowflt['tipo_de_sacion'];
$filter3 = $rowflt['Clase_de_actividad'];
$filter4 = $rowflt['estado_del_expediente']; ```
````

Ahora, la consulta la estoy haciendo así:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from `p_sancionatorios` 
                           WHERE cl_act='$filter1' 
                           AND y_con='$filter2' 
                           AND cl_res_cal='$filter3' 
                           AND status='$filter4';");
```

El problema es que, al dejar el condicional AND en toda la consulta, si hay algo que no cumpla con las 4 condiciones al tiempo, no muestra nada.

Ya probé modificandola cambiando el condicional AND por OR, pero en este caso no aplica la busqueda ya que siempre muestra los mismos registros.

lo que busco es que asi solo tenga uno o dos de los filtros aplicados busque por esos criterior, o si le aplico tres o cuatro filtros haga la busqueda.

Se que mi problema esta en la consulta, pero no se como solucionarlo, espero me puedan iluminar, quedo atento a su amable ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Podrias probar con el operador in, quedaria de esta forma; `Select * from tutabla where tucampo in (filtro1,filtro2,filtro3) `, el "in" lo que hace es igualar a cualquier miembro de la lista o esto: `Select * from tutabla where tucampo = ANY (filtro1,filtro2,filtro3) `, esto lo que hace es comparar con cada valor o filtro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun puedo ver, tu problema es mas de logica que de mysql...

Al hacer un query con una condicion multiple (4 campos) primero debes saber si vienen los cuatro datos y definir tu consulta de acuerdo a eso...

Tambien tienes que estar seguro de lo que quieres, pues no es lo mismo que selecciones los que cumplan con cualquiera de las condiciones (OR) a que selecciones solo los que cumplan con todas las condiciones (AND).

Por lo tanto:

para saber si vienen los cuatro datos tienes que checar que tengan contenido, ej.

```
if ($rowflt['año']>"") // o (isset($rowflt['año']) si viene de un post
```

una vez que sepas cuales son los filtros definidos y que tipo de consulta quieres hacer (OR/AND) debes armar la consulta incluyendo solo los campos definidos.

ej. si solo tienes filtro 2 y filtro cuatro y quieres que se cumplan las dos condiciones, la consulta debe quedar asi:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from `p_sancionatorios` 
                           WHERE y_con='$filter2' 
                           AND status='$filter4';");
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes razón el tema es mas de lógica que de la misma consulta mysql, ya organice mejor lo que quiero y con base en ello, estoy seguro que obtendré un mejor resultado